# Is there a way to only encode an XML opening tag in go xml package?

Tags: xml, go, encoding

I have a type,

```
type Example struct {
  XMLName xml.Name `xml:"example example"`
  Attr1 string `xml:"attr1,attr"`
}
```

If I try to encode this using [xml.Encoder](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Encoder) to stdout writer,

```
enc := xml.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
v := &Example{Attr1: "attr1"}

if err := enc.Encode(v); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
}
```

it encodes this element with the closing tag, i.e.

```
<example xmlns="example" attr1="attr1"></example>
```

But I want to encode only the opening tag, i.e.

```
<example xmlns="example" attr1="attr1">
```

Is this possible?

Comment: No, because just the opening tag is not XML. XY problem?

Comment: @Volker I agree. But I have to write this opening tag and then write bunch of other stuff before I close it.

Comment: It would be best if you can embed your other stuff into the struct. If it is hard to achieve, maybe you can use a XML parser to parse it back and utilize the parser node for more convenient manipulation. If you need further help, please show details on your other stuff.

Comment: If you have to just print this opening tag use fmt.Printf taking care of escaping of attr1 yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [`Marshaller`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshaler) interface for your struct and do whatever you want.

As a hack you can add a dummy member to the parent struct and do custom stuff there:

```
type ExampleInner struct {
}

func (ExampleInner) MarshalXML(e *Encoder, start StartElement) error {
  // Do your custom stuff here
  return nil
}

type Example struct {
  XMLName xml.Name `xml:"example example"`
  Attr1 string `xml:"attr1,attr"`
  Inner ExampleInner
}
```